# TYPO3 History of file Media

Tags: file, logging, typo3, typo3-11.x

I have TYPO3 11.5

I need to have modification history for files.
I noticed that TYPO3 keeps the history of changing metadata such as title and description but if I replace the pdf file with another TYPO3 does not track that I replaced the pdf file.

What can i do?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please rephrase it. Maybe you can use a tool like DeepL or Google Translate to have a more meaningful explanation of your problem.

Comment: I used google tranlsate I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

How do you exchange the pdf file? If you do that directly in the file system, TYPO3 cannot track the change. If you change the file via the TYPO3 backend, the `tstamp` field in the database should be updated.

Comment: I use the backend. I click on "replace" button but in history i see only metadata changes, not the old file uploaded